# How to force save address book during checkout

Tags: onepage-checkout

I am making a module that enables automatic shipments for our clients. There is a new step in the checkout process that allows customers to choose how often they receive this order. If they are making a new re-recurring order I want to be able to force them to save their shipping address in the address book so that they can receive this order multiple times. (we are also developing a secure way to charge their cards as well, so thats been thought of as well.)

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange! [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So I have overridden the one page javascript to save the order to a seperate controller action if its a recurring order. (a real order shouldn't be created yet) I have added a $billing->setSaveInAddressBook(1) to the logic thats saving my recurring order. This doesn't work though. I'll post updates as I try different strategies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the code necessary to ensure that new entries in the address book get created when my order is finished. This works because when someone is checkout out with a recurring order I have overridden the onepage javascript to send them to a different controller action to finish the order. This way I have control over what happens their, and I didn't have to override any of the create order logic in the onepage controller.

The following code is in my child of Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage.

```
$quote = $this->getQuote();
$quote_billing = $quote->getBillingAddress();
$quote_shipping = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $current_customer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session")->getCustomer();
    if (empty($quote_billing) === false && $quote_billing->getCustomerAddressId() == null) {
        $custom_billing_address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
        $custom_billing_address->setData($this->getAddressDataFromQuote($quote_billing));
        $custom_billing_address->setCustomer($current_customer);
        $default_customer_billing = $current_customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        if (empty($default_customer_billing)) {
            $custom_billing_address->setIsDefaultBilling('1');
        }
        $custom_billing_address->save();
        $quote_billing->setCustomerAddressId($custom_billing_address->getEntityId());
        $quote->setBillingAddress($quote_billing);

        if ($quote_shipping->getSameAsBilling()) {
            $default_customer_shipping = $current_customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
            if (empty($default_customer_shipping)) {
                $custom_billing_address->setIsDefaultShipping('1');
                $custom_billing_address->save();
            }

            $quote_shipping->setCustomerAddressId($custom_billing_address->getEntityId());
            $quote->setShippingAddress($quote_shipping);
        }
    }
```

The above code is referencing $this->getAddressDataFromQuote. This is just a simple function to extract address specific fields from the quote address. Here it is.

```
public function getAddressDataFromQuote($quote_address) {
    $columns_to_transfer = array(
        'firstname',
        'middlename',
        'lastname',
        'company',
        'street',
        'city',
        'region',
        'region_id',
        'postcode',
        'country_id',
        'telephone',
        'fax',
    );
    $array_to_return = array();
    foreach($columns_to_transfer as $address_key) {
        $array_to_return[$address_key] = $quote_address->getData($address_key);
    }
    return $array_to_return;
}
```

After this you would do something simular for the shipping address as they might be using a different address for shipping. You will need to make sure that if they are using the same address that a seperate address in the address book is not being created as that was obviously not the users intention. Also if the customer does not have default shipping and billing addresses set then I set the new address as the default as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code to save the customer address easily.

Add the below into `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/model/type/Onepage.php` 318 line inside the swith case

```
$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
 $log_in_customer_id = $customerData->getId();


               $billing = clone $address;
               $billing->unsAddressId()->unsAddressType();
               $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
               $customAddress->setData($billing->getData())
               ->setCustomerId($log_in_customer_id)
               ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
               ->setIsDefaultShipping('0')
               ->setSaveInAddressBook('0');
               $customAddress->save();
```

Add the same code in shipping with a change of $shipping instead of $billing and use the if conditions if necessary.

It is working with Magento1910.